# Symfony2-How to use access a service from outside of a controller

Tags: symfony

In my Symfony2 controller, this works fine:

```php
$uploadManager = $this->get('upload.upload_manager');
```

**but when I move it to a custom Listener:**

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Acme\UploadBundle\Upload\UploadManager;

class PersonChange
{
    public function postRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

        $uploadManager = $this->get('ep_upload.upload_manager');
        echo "the upload dir is " . $uploadManager->getUploadDir();
    }
}
```

I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Acme\MainBundle\Listener\PersonChange::get() in /home/frank/...
```

I know I must need a use statement but don't know what to use.

Comment: This should provide a possible solution: [How do I get services dependencies in a custom class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622382/how-do-i-get-services-dependencies-in-a-custom-class)

Answer (score 16):

**Update: Defining controllers as services is no longer officially recommended in Symfony.**

The `get()` method in the `Controller` class is just a helper method to get services from the container, and it was meant to get new Symfony2 developers up to speed faster. <s>Once people get comfortable with the framework and dependency injection, it's recommended to [define controllers as services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html) and inject each required service explicitly.</s>

Since your `PersonChange` class is not a controller and doesn't extend the `Controller` class, you don't have that `get()` helper method. Instead, you need to define your class as a service and inject needed services explicitly. Read the [Service Container chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) for details.

Comment: Literally the first sentence: Defining controllers as services is **not officially recommended** by Symfony.

Comment: 4 years have passed since my answer. Best practices evolve.

Comment: Yes, but this answer is still easily found when Googling. It should be updated to be inline with current Symfony practices.

Comment: So what IS the recommended way to do it anno 2016?

Answer (score 12):

As I ran into the exact same problem maybe I can help

What Elnur said is perfectly fine and I'll just try to pop up a real life example.

In my case I wanted to access

```
$lucenemanager = $this->get('ivory.lucene.manager')
```

Even by extending the controller I couldn't get it to work while the controller does access the container (I still did not understand why)

In config.yml my listener (searchindexer.listener) is declared as follow :

```
   services:
    searchindexer.listener:
        class: ripr\WfBundle\Listener\SearchIndexer
        arguments:
              luceneSearch: "@ivory_lucene_search"
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
```

A service (ivory.lucene.search) is passed as argument in my service/listener.

Then in my class

```
protected $lucenemanager;

        public function __construct($luceneSearch)
        {
            $this->lucenemanager = $luceneSearch;
        }
```

Then you can use the get method against $this

Answer (score 8):

An approach that always works, despite not being the best practice in OO

```
global $kernel;
$assetsManager = $kernel->getContainer()->get('acme_assets.assets_manager');‏
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access a Service, define it in the class constructor:

```
class PersonChange{
    protected $uploadManager;
    public function __construct(UploadManager $uploadManager){
        $this->uploadManager = $uploadManager;
    }
    // Now you can use $this->uploadManager.
}
```

Now you can pass the Service as argument when calling the class (example 1) or define the clas itself as a Service (**recommended**, example 2)

Example 1:

```
use Acme\PersonChange;
class appController{
    function buzzAction(){
        $uploadManager = $this->get('upload.upload_manager');
        $personChange = new PersonChange($uploadManager);
```

Example 2 **(better)**:

Define `PersonChange` as a Service itself, and define the other Service as an argument in services.yml file:

```
 # app/config/services.yml
services:
    upload.upload_manager:
        class:     AppBundle\uploadManager

    PersonChange:
        class:     AppBundle\PersonChange
        arguments: ['@upload.upload_manager']
```

In this way, you don't have to bother with the `upload_manager` service in the Controller, since it's implicitely passed as an argument for the constructor, so your Controller can be:

```
class appController{
    function buzzAction(){
        $personChange = $this->get('PersonChange');
```